# How do I use variables created in different multiprocessing Processes?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Sorry, a bit of a newbie with Python.

Can anyone help with the below code?
I'm trying to write two dataframes, created by two separate multiprocessing Processes to the same excel file.

EDIT: this is simplified code. In my actual project the dataframes are built using pd.read_sql() on different connections. If this won't bring about any noticeable in terms of speed, please let me know. I just assumed running it normally would mean waiting for the first connection's SQL query to run before the second connection's.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing

def Test1():
global df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

def Test2():
    global df2
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [20, 40, 60, 40, 30, 60, 90]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
Proc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Test1)
Proc2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Test2)
Proc1.start()
Proc2.start()
Proc1.join()
Proc2.join()
writer = 
pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop','Test.xlsx') , engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test Title',index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Test Title2',index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Test Title']
worksheet = writer.sheets['Test Title2']
writer.save()
```

It doesn't help that I don't know the terminology in order to search out the answer. So apologies if this is a duplicate of a question asked by someone more Python-literate than myself.

Also, the error message:

```
line 37, in <module>
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test Title',index=False)
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: I can't really see the use-case of multiprocessing here. It's probably slower than serially creating the DFs

Comment: Please check where your bottleneck is. Last time I worked with excel in python the problem was with the library/package and there was no need for multiprocessing. Just for a new package.

Comment: Also if you have two processes for one file they might block each other.

Comment: @roganjosh, sorry, this is a trimmed down version of the code I'm actually using.
Each of the dataframes are actually created by SQL queries that take a while to run. So I'm trying to run them concurrently

Answer (score 0):

Using `global` with multiprocessing does not work like you seem to think that it does.

Both `Test1` and `Test2` are run in a *separate* process, that shares *no data* with the parent process.

Some things that you could do:

- Create a `multiprocessing.Queue` *before* starting the processes. The processes can then use that `Queue` to send data back to the parent process. The data probably has to be able to be pickled. The parent writes the data to the excel file.
- Have each process write its own dataframe to a file and then send a message to the parent that it is done. The parent merges them into an excel file when all processes are done. A variant of this is to use memory mapped files (`mmap`). The latter works well if the amount of data does not ecxeed available memory.

Which approach works best depends on a lot of factors. For small amounts of data using a `Queue` is a good option. For large amounts of data using intermediate files (especially on an SSD) can be a good option.